# Scope variable in java

Tags: java

I have a code,
we i need find scope variable at the piratical point where i have commented.
but i have doubt does`args` comes under scope variable?

Here is code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static int foo(int num) {
       int other_num = 2;
       // num , other_num
       return num % other_num;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int odd = 0;

       int x = 13;
       for (int value = 0; value < x; value++) {
           // value , odd , x 
           boolean local_odd = false;
           int r = foo(value);
           if (r == 1) {
               // value , odd , x , local_odd, r
               local_odd = true;
           } else {
               int div = value/2;
               System.out.println(div +" divides "+ value);
               // value , odd , x , local_odd, r , div
           }
           if (local_odd) {
               odd++;
           }
       }
       System.out.println(odd+" odd numbers smaller than "+x);
       // odd , x
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear and proper . Please elaborate

Comment: Sorry, but _"write down the scope variable at the piratical point"_ is not understandable. "Piratical" means "having to do with pirates", which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: What should a "scope variable" denote? IMO it is nonesense. Every variable _has_ its scope where it is visible and valid.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `args` is in main(). You can check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3) out. `args` is a method parameter therefore valid only in main(), if that is what you are asking.